# Find latest available Chrome version (on Linux, eg from a shell script)

Tags: google-chrome

How can I find the latest version of Google Chrome from a shell script (e.g. `bash`) on Linux ?

For ChromeDriver, I can do this:

```
curl https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE
```

Can I do something similar for Chrome?

---

**Background to question**
T
his needs to be done in a pipeline and there is no local install of Chrome, no tools to inspect packages (rpm, deb, and the like). The reason I want this is so that I can download the latest version as a numbered package. I could do this

```
wget -O https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

but that results in a file called `google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` rather than one that is version stamped such as `google-chrome-stable_73.0.3683.103-1_amd64.deb`.

If I know the version in advance, I can get a version-stamped file using this:

```
GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION=73.0.3683.103-1
wget http://dl.google.com/linux/deb/pool/main/g/google-chrome-stable/google-chrome-stable_${GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION}_amd64.deb
```

So what I'm really looking for is either generic URL that always returns the latest version-stamped file or a way to set `GOOGLE_CHROME_VERSION` in the above.

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Ubuntu Desktop like mine 16.04, here is the command

```
google-chrome --version
```

ref. https://askubuntu.com/a/505532/22308

Comment: The idea is to find the latest version in order to download and install that version, not see what version one has already installed.

Comment: Then correct the question title. It is missleading for now.